# Fitting a statement in a long list of equivalent results

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

**Theorem.** Suppose that $D\subset \mathbb C$ is a connected open set. The following are equivalent.

1. Either $D=\mathbb C$ or $D$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb D$.
2. $D$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb D$.
3. $D$ is simply connected.
4. Ind($\gamma,z)=0$ for every smooth closed curve $\gamma$ in $D$ and every $z\in\mathbb C\backslash D$.
5. $\mathbb C_{\infty}\backslash D$ is connected.
6. If $f\in H(D)$ then there exists a sequence of polynomials $(P_{n})$ such that $P_{n}\to f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $D$.
7. $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz=0$ for every $f\in H(D)$ and every smooth closed curve $\gamma$ in $D$.
8. If $f\in H(D)$ then there exists $F\in H(D)$ with $F'=f$.
9. If $u:D\to \mathbb R$ is harmonic then $u=\mathbb R$e$(f)$ for some $f\in H(D)$.
10. If $f\in H(D)$ has no zero in $D$ then there exists $L\in H(D)$ with $f=e^{L}$.
11. If $f\in H(D)$ has no zero in $D$ then there exists $g\in H(D)$ with $g^{2}=f$.

The proof to this theorem can be found in David C. Ullrich's book Complex Made Simple, and it is surprisingly nice that it was proven as a chain (as in $1\implies 2\implies\cdots\implies 11\implies 1$).

Let $D$ and $G$ be connected open subsets of $\mathbb C$ with $D\subset G$. If $(f,D)$ is a function element which admits continuation along every path in $G$ which starts at a point of $D$ then we say that $(f,D)$ *admits unrestricted continuation* in $G$.

Now, consider the following:

**Proposition.** Let $D$ be an open connected subset of the plane. $D$ is simply connected if and only if for every functional element $(f,A)$, $A\subset D$ that admits unrestricted continuation in $D$ there exists a function $F\in H(D)$ such that $f=F\rvert_{A}$.

Between what numbers in the theorem would this proposition fit the best, in order to obtain a chain-like proof of the theorem?

Comment: What are the definitions of "$D$ is holomorphic to $\Bbb D$" and "admits unrestricted continuation in $D$"?

Comment: I meant to write homeomorphic. I have added the definition of unrestricted continuation.

Comment: You don't have to maintain the chain.  You can prove your statement from any of the equivalent ones, then prove any of the equivalent ones from your statement to show yours is equivalent to all of them.  The chain is just one convenient way of showing equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good place for the propostion would be between (7) and (8):

- Fix a base point $z_0\in D$. If $f$ admits unrestricted continuation in $D$, then that gives us a way to try to define $F\in H(D)$: draw a path from $z_0$ to $z\in D$ and define $F(z)$ according to the continuation of $f$ along that path. (7) allows one to prove that this definition is well defined (independent of the path).
- Again fix a base point $z_0$, and note that $\int_\gamma f(w)\,dw$ where $\gamma$ is any path from $z_0$ to $z$ gives unrestricted continuation in $D$ of the function element that equals $0$ at $z_0$. (This isn't quite right maybe, do we need an analytic function in a neighborhood of $z_0$...?) Then there is $F\in H(D)$ that extends this function, and one shows that $F'=f$.

Comment: I am unsure how to prove that 7 implies the independence of the path of F. Can you please elaborate?