# Existence of some functions

Tags: complex-analysis

In my algebraic topology exam, the following question was asked as follows which I was not able to answer:
$ f $ is a holomorphic function from a simply connected space $U$ to $\Bbb C^*.$ Then there exist (a)$log f $ from $U$ to $\Bbb C^*$.
(b)$h$ from $U$ to $\Bbb C^*$ such that $h^2=f$.
I am not able to think about the way I should proceed. It seems like that I have to use covering spaces and lifts but I am not able to find a solution.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452127/fitting-a-statement-in-a-long-list-of-equivalent-results/4452223#4452223)

Comment: In (a), the codomain should be $\Bbb C$ instead of $\Bbb C^*$. A standard way to proceed is to consider $\log f(u_0) + \int_{u_0}^z \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)} \,dw$ where $u_0,z\in U$ with $u_0$ fixed.

Comment: (b) comes from (a) by taking $\log$, dividing by $2$, taking $\exp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other, more elementary answers. However, as this was a question in algebraic topology, I think the following is the "usual/expected" answer.

1. Notice that $\exp:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}^*$ is a covering map so $(\mathbb{C}, \exp)$ is the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^*$. By the usual properties of universal covers (and by simple connectedness of $U$) there exists a continuous map $h$ such that $\exp(h)=f$. It is now not hard to prove that $h$ has to be analytic and the result follows.
2. Follows from $(1)$: since $\ln(f)$ is well defined and holomorphic, take $h=\exp\left(\frac{\ln(f)}2\right)$ and you're done.